# Как через execl сделать файл исполняемым?

Tags: linux, c, chmod

Необходимо через execl сделать файл исполняемым, к сожалению компилятор ругается

```
execl(“/bin/bash”,"chmod +x”,1.txt, NULL)
```

Comment: Необходимо использовать execl

Comment: Не очень хорошо знаю linux, но разве `chmod`  не есть исполнимая программа? Вызывайте не bash, а ее. Типа `execl("chmod","chmod","+x","1.txt",NULL);` - ну, а с правами доступа смотрите сами...

Comment: Если компилятор ругается, нужно привести текст ошибки в вопросе. Ругаться может как на имя файла без кавычек, так и на косые кавычки вместо обычных прямых.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка компиляции тут, забыли кавычки:

```
execl(“/bin/bash”,"chmod +x”,1.txt, NULL)
                             ^^^^^
```

Посмотрите мануал [man execl](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execl), и сделайте как там написано:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    return execl ("/bin/chmod", "chmod", "+x", argv[1] , (char*) NULL);
}
```

```
$ ./mkexe 1.txt; ll 1.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 me me 0 Aug 28 14:23 1.txt
```

Comment: @insolor А зачем правку откатили, чтобы было как в оригинале? Я и не заметил, что там юникодовские кавычки ))

Comment: Да, сначала думал что это у вас так странно вставилось, потом посмотрел что в вопросе так же. Причем без выделения кодом этого не видно, поэтому скорее всего вы и не заметили.